# Calling an instance of an object into another controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, mongoid

I have a report object that renders fine, however I have a reportapproval object that I want to pass to the report view so I can run a calculation within the report view. Each user has_one report and each report has multiple reportapprovals. How can I call a specific reportapproval and send that instance to the report controller or view. Here is my report controller.

```
class Users::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @report = Report.find(params[:id])
      authorize @report
  end
end
```

I tried to pass

```
@reportapproval = Reportapprovals.where(user_id: @report.user_id).first
```

in the show method but the ReportController wont recognize the Reportapproval.

How can I pass the instance to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just do

```
@reportapproval = @report.reportapprovals.first
```

Comment: Wow! You are correct! I believe that got it! However if this report has more than one reportapproval wont it not access the other reportapprovals. How can I call the reportapproval instance attached to that admin/user from that report instance.

Comment: You can add an extra `params` in your url, say call it `approval_id`. Then you can do @reportapproval = @report.reportapprovals.where(id: params[:approval_id]).first

Comment: You got it sir! Made a small tweak and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `reportapprovals` records in `show` method itself, The `@report` and `@reportapproval` you can access on views `reports/show.html.erb`

```
class Users::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    @reportapproval = @report.reportapprovals.first
    authorize @report
  end
end
```